# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parser' in slate3k

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying extract some information from first few pages of the pdf documents using slate3k as follows:

```
for i in range(table.shape[0]):
    print(i)
    download_path = pdf_dir + '/'+ table.iloc[i,6]
    if(path.exists(download_path)):
        if download_path.endswith('.pdf'):
            file = open(download_path,'rb')
            doc = slate3k.PDF(file)
            doc = ' '.join(doc[:2])
            doc = re.sub("\n","",doc)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-474429c993a7> in <module>
     12         if download_path.endswith('.pdf'):
     13             file = open(download_path,'rb')
---> 14             doc = slate3k.PDF(file)
     15             doc = ' '.join(doc[:2])
     16             doc = re.sub("\n","",doc)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\slate3k\classes.py in __init__(self, file, password, just_text, check_extractable, char_margin, line_margin, word_margin)
     57 
     58         if PYTHON_3:
---> 59             self.doc = PDFDocument()
     60             self.parser.set_document(self.doc)
     61             self.doc.set_parser(self.parser)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parser'
```

Can anyone please help me understand what the error is? And how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Check thé link below if it can help you: https://github.com/timClicks/slate/issues/43

Comment: It seems some People have manage it by seeing the file /src/slate/classes.py carefully,  and just added 'not' before PYTHON_3 in if condition.

if not PYTHON_3:

in line number 55 and 69, then it worked for me.

Comment: @Renaud Hi! I changed the lines 58 and 72 from ```if PYTHON_3:``` to ```if not PYTHON_3:``` but there was no change. And the change suggested in the issue raised on github was not required, since it already had ```self.doc = PFDocument(self.parser)```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and the reason why this error appears is the pyinstaller. It seems to interfere with the API of slate3k.

What I have done to solve this problem

1. pip uninstall pdfminer
2. pip uninstall slate3k

(Optional - In my case I also had to uninstall pdfminer3, so:)
3. pip uninstall pdfminer3

4. pip install slate3k

Now it should work.

EDIT: it seems like pyinstaller can cause the same error therefore you could try the same thing as above with pyinstaller = pdfminer.